# ¿Como puedo hacer para realizar este arreglo?

Tags: c++, array, vectores

Básicamente me pidieron realizar un arreglo de ***"n"*** elementos, llenarlos hasta la mitad con números al azar **(menores a 800)** y después empezar a generar números al azar **(Menores a 1000)** para llenarlo.

Ahora, cuando el numero que se generó es mayor al ultimo elemento del vector, se agrega
(Es decir, si tengo 10 elementos donde solo se llenaron 5, que este numero generado se guarde en la posición 6)
Pero, si es menor o igual, elimine este ultimo elemento.
Pude hacer el código para que se llene hasta la mitad con números random. Pero el primer elemento es mayor de 1000 y no se como continuar para realizar ese  "if" (O es lo que creo que debería utilizar)

PD: No debo usar puntero. -/- El valor ***"N"*** Se ingresa como primer dato.
PD2: Esto tiene que repetirse hasta que al menos pase 1 de los siguientes casos:
1.- El vector quede vacío
2.- El vector se llene.
3.- Se generen un total de ***N*10*** números al azar.

> Codigo

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include<time.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <new>
#include <climits>
using namespace std;

void mostrar(int b[], int N){
    
    for(int i = 0; i<N; i++){
        cout<<b[i]<<" "<<endl;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int negative = -1;
    int small = 1;
    int large = INT_MAX;
    try {
        new int[negative];           // tamaño negativo
        new int[small]{1,2,3};       // demasiados inicializadores
        new int[large][1000000];     // demasiado grande
    } catch(const std::bad_array_new_length &e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << '\n';
    }

    int N,mitad;
    int* a = new int [N];
    
    cout<<"Digite el numero de Elementos que va a tener el arreglo: ";
    cin>>N;
    
mitad = round(N/2);

cout << mitad;
    for(int i=0; i<mitad; i++){
        a[i] = i + (rand() % 1000+1);
    }

    mostrar(a, N);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta ¿Qué elementos deben ser mayores a 800 y cuáles mayores o menores a 1000? ¿los elementos son realmente aleatorios o deben ser ascendentes aleatoriamente?

Comment: Hola, la mitad del arreglo tiene que ser con números aleatorios menores a 800... 
Para agregar números nuevos, tienen que realizarse aleatoriamente menores a 1000 
Pero solo se añaden si estos son mayores al ultimo agregado. En caso de ser menor o igual, se tienen que eliminar del vector. 
Ejemplo:

Ingrese "N" de elementos.
> 5

0.- 25
1.- 200
2.- 0
3.- 0
4.- 0
Se empiezan a dar Números random: 
1.- 20 (No pasa nada)
2.- 25 (No pasa nada)
3.- 200 (Se borra el elemento 1 del vector)
4.- 500 (Al ser mayor de 25, se añade al elemento 1 del vector)
y así. 
Se logra entender?

Comment: Lo que dices no tiene sentido, si "*la mitad del arreglo tiene que ser con números aleatorios menores a 800*" no pueden "*realizarse aleatoriamente menores a 1000*" ya que al menos 200 números serán mayores a 800 (incumpliendo la primera premisa), después dices "*se añaden si son mayores al ultimo agregado*" pero en el ejemplo que pones vas agregando números y "*borra el elemento 1 del vector*" ¿No habías dicho que se tenía que mirar el "*último agregado*"?

Answer (score 0):

una manera seria asi, aunque el algoritmo se puede mejorar mas.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n;
    cout<<"Ingrese un numero: ";
    cin>>n;
    int t1=800/(n/2);
    int t2=200/(n/2);
    int vec[n];
    srand(time(NULL));
    int num;
    vec[0]=1;
    for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++){
        if(i<(n/2)){
            num=vec[i]+rand()%((vec[i]+t1+1)-vec[i]);
            if(vec[i]<num){
                vec[i+1]=num;
            }else i--;
        }else{
            num=vec[i]+rand()%((vec[i]+2)-vec[i]);
            //cout<<num<<">"<<vec[i]<<":::"<<i<<endl;
            if(vec[i]<num){
                vec[i+1]=num;
            }else i--;
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cout<<vec[i]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```